# Session in Parent

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a webform that inherits from a .cs class (which heradates from Page)

```
WebForm1.aspx =>  BaseWebForm.cs  => Page
```

I am trying to access to the current session from BaseWebForm, but within it's context, its null. I call BaseWebForm by :

Form page

```
WebForm1 :BaseWebForm  
public WebForm1(): Base()
{
}
```

BaseWebForm.cs class

```
public BaseWebForm  ()
{
                      //access  HttpContext.Current.Session["User_xComics"]
}
```

In BaseWebForm  context the session is null, but in WebForm1's context the session does exists. What's the problem?

Comment: What is "heradates"? I think you mean "derives".

Comment: What method of your `BaseWebForm` are you modifying? `HttpContext.Current` can be null under certain circumstances. What happens if you're in the `OnLoad` method and access `this.Request`?

Comment: have you thought about initializing `HttpContext.Current.Session["User_xComics"]` in the `OnSessionStart()` in the `Global.asax` file

Comment: Dai, Please see the edits.  MethodMan I havent try that, I'll try

Comment: you will also need to code for that value in the `Page_Load` event using either the `if(IsPostBack){}` or `if(!IsPostBack){}` checking the value if `string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["User_xComics"]){}` then force login else redirect and or let user continue

Answer (score 0):

`BaseWebForm` class should inherit from `System.Web.UI.Page`. You should probably only use the page life cycle events such as `Page_Load` rather than doing `Session` work in the constructor.

As soon as the user logs in, you should probably initialize `HttpContext.Current.Session["User_xComics"]`. If this is using Windows Authentication, the best place for that is in the `Session_Start` function of your Global Application Class (.asax.cs)

Comment: BaseWebForm does inherits from System.Web.UI.Page. The thing is that I want to verify user type before let the user acces to the page

Comment: @Flezcano then you should perhaps show more code than what you are currently showing.. also read up on `OnSessionStart` and how to use it.. there are many ways to check what you're trying to do but one can not offer an exact solution based on what little information you have provided in my opinion...

Comment: @Flezcano Then do that in one of the page lifecycle events like I said. `Page_Load` and `Page_PreInit` seem like good candidates.